# Bazel Python: Stacktraces seems useless?

Tags: python, bazel

I started playing around with Bazel for Python. My Python script is running (yay) but unfortunately when it throws the stacktraces refer to all files within Bazel's runfiles directory. This makes sense given that bazel executes a copy of the script located in that particular folder. However, this renders any form of IDE integration useless. PyCharm autolinks Python stacktraces to the corresponding files and line numbers -- an awesome feature for quickly following stacktraces. With Bazel this still works but instead of linking to my actual project directory it links to runfiles directory which is semi useful. Sure, I can look at the source, but I now have the same file open twice in my IDE and have to hop to the one actually located in my project directory to make changes. I understand that this is really hard to fix based on how Bazel fetches dependencies and would only work with some form of virtual envrionemt instead IMO. Is there anything I'm missing when using Bazel with Python or is this just how life with Bazel and Python is?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bazel plugin for PyCharm (see [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8609-bazel/versions)). The plugin is also available for CLion and  IntelliJ. It should integrate your Bazel project nicely into your IDE with all the comfort you are used to.